# Enable preview features with jlinked java launcher

Tags: java, jlink, java-13

I am using Java 13 preview features, but I can't find the option in jlink to add the "--enable-preview" flag to the java command inside of the launcher script jlink generates.

As you can see, the launcher script that is generated is

```sh
#!/bin/sh
JLINK_VM_OPTIONS=
DIR=`dirname $0`
$DIR/java $JLINK_VM_OPTIONS -m wla_server/net.saga.snes.dev.wlalanguageserver.Main $@
```

However, I don't know how to get the script to be generated with `JLINK_VM_OPTIONS=--enable-preview` using the jlink command.

My jlink command is

```sh
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jlink \
  --module-path target/classes:target/dependency \
  --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH \
  --launcher launcher=wla_server/net.saga.snes.dev.wlalanguageserver.Main \
  --output dist/linux \
  --vm=server \
  --compress 2
```

Comment: Where's the code? What difficulties are you facing?

Comment: @MerajalMaksud what does the code matter? `jlink` is used to create an executable (runtime image) and OP wants to pass the mentioned option to it

Comment: @SummersPitman doesn't `jlink` create a directory structure that contians a `bin` folder with the `java` executable that accepts `--enable-preview`? (OpenJDK13 does on Windows)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger This seems to be about the separate launch script that `jlink` generates when you use the `--launcher` option. I don't think there is a way to add `--enable-preview` to the generated command automatically, so you'd have to edit the script to include it manually.

Comment: @JornVernee I agree, script must be edited or maybe [`jpackage`](http://jdk.java.net/jpackage/) can help (Java 14?)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the launcher script needs to be edited.  The script at least creates a OPTIONS variable I can sed the option into as part of my build.  I don't think that this is an option in jlink right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added the following sed command to my build script :

```sh
sed -i 's/JLINK_VM_OPTIONS=.*/JLINK_VM_OPTIONS=--enable-preview/' dist/linux/bin/launcher
```

This edits the launcher script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
JLINK_VM_OPTIONS=--enable-preview
DIR=`dirname $0`
$DIR/java $JLINK_VM_OPTIONS -m wla_server/net.saga.snes.dev.wlalanguageserver.Main $@
```

Which works well enough.